# Join multiple tables with Select and Where clause by Lamda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 table like below

Table 1: `Brand`

```
+-------+---------+-------+
|Code(k)| Name    | Sale  | *Code - set Primary Key
+-------+---------+-------+  
| AP    | Apple   | False |  
+-------+---------+-------+  
| SS    | SamSung | False |  
+-------+---------+-------+  
| N     | Nokia   | False |  
+-------+---------+-------+
```

Table 2: `Category`
*(`Code` in Table 1: `Brand` and `Brand` in table Table 2: `Category` is same)*

```
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+
| ID(k) | Category    | Brand | Manager |  *ID - set Primary Key
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 1     | BasicPhone  | SS    | M1      |
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 2     | SmartPhone  | AP    | M1      |
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 3     | CameraPhone | SS    | M1      |
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 4     | Tablet      | SS    | M1      |
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 5     | Iphone      | AP    | M1      |
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+
| 6     | Ipad        | AP    | M1      |
+-------+-------------+-------+---------+
```

Table 3: `Product`

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Category    | CategoryDes | Description |  * no Primary Key
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| BasicPhone  | NoCamera    | Contact     |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| SmartPhone  | Camera      | TakePhoto   |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| CameraPhone | GoodCamera  | Selfie      |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Tablet      | BigScreen   | ReadNews    |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Iphone      | Iphone7     | Something.. |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Ipad        | Ipad2       | Ipad...     |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

How can I Join Table 1: `Brand` and Table 3: `Product` into Table 2: `Category` by `Lambda expression`

The result I want like this

```
+-----+------------+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| ID  | Category   | Brand | Manager | Name    | Sale  | CategoryDes | Description |
+-----+------------+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| 1   | BasicPhone | SS    | M1      | SamSung | False | NoCamera    | Contact     |
+-----+------------+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| 2   | SmartPhone | AP    | M1      | Apple   | False | Camera      | TakePhoto   |
+-----+------------+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
|                                ...........                                       |
+-----+------------+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
| ... | null       | null  | N       | Nokia   | False | null        | null        | *null (allowed)
+-----+------------+-------+---------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+
```

Update:

I tried to Join Table 1 to Table 2

```
var test = db.Brand.Join(db.Category , u => u.Code, y => y.Brand,(u, y) => new { u, y });
```

Comment: First you have to show us what you have tried along with any errors and an explanation of why it does not work as intended.

Comment: @Darkonekt Quite difficult for me when join 3 tables at the same time. I updated my post.

Comment: Your Join looks good, where is the problem ? Cannot append another Join in the same way ? Why you ask for a Where-Clause or a Select ? There is no Manager "N" in your table 2, so how can you expect an N to be in your Output ?

Comment: There is many ways to do this.  Depends on many things.  One way is to get the main table and then use the "Include" functionality to include Navigation Properties.   As for showing your code is a requirement in Stack Overflow to show full examples of code... Since StackOverflow is not a code provider website. But rather a troubleshooting blog.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @Holger is right, you're on the right track, just need another join. Something like this:

```cs
 test = db.Brand
    .Join(db.Category, b => b.Code, c => c.Brand, (b, c) => new { b, c })
    .Join(db.Product, x => x.c.Category, p => p.Category, (x, p) => new { x.b, x.c, p })
```

Disclaimer, I didn't test this.

Comment: Also, you may want to start your join on `Product`.